# Почему не получается загрузить файлы кода на github через GitHub Desktop?

Tags: git, github

Создал на сайте github репизаторий, клонировал его на GitHub Desktop, нашел его , скопировал файлы туда в папку с названием slider3.github.io, но те файлы, которые загрузил, не появляются в GitHub Desktop, что я делаю не так?

Пересмотрел видео как копировать в github документы, там у людей получается, у меня не получается, не появляются файлы. В файле документы есть, а в GitHub Desktop не появляются.

вложил изображения

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBdHL.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeA4U.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njcn5.png]

Comment: вы хотите ваш проэкт добавить в github репизаторию? Я правильно понял?

Comment: да, правильно  все верно

Comment: Можно и через терминал сделать, отправить код?

Comment: я уже разобрался , загрузил )))